# triggering java events from different classes

Tags: java, swing

so i have this JFrame window that has a button that opens a different JFrame, the goal from the second window is upon clicking its ok button a table refresh in the first window, but i'm having a hard time solving the issue and didn't find any answer after about an hour of searching (it's not a lot i know but i'm pressed for time). so this is my code and  i hope you guys help me out.

the code for the first window:

```
// the event that i want to trigger
public void refreshTable() {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = new dbcon().getResultSet("select * from users", new Vector<Object>());   
            Vector<Vector<Object>> v = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
            while(rs.next()) {
                Vector<Object> element = new Vector<Object>();
                element.add(rs.getInt("id"));
                element.add(rs.getString("name"));
                element.add(rs.getString("uname"));
                element.add(rs.getString("pwd"));
                element.add(rs.getString("date"));
                element.add(rs.getInt("admin"));
                v.add(element);
            }
            DefaultTableModel md = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            md.setRowCount(0);
            for(int i=v.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
                md.addRow(v.elementAt(i));
            }
        }catch(Exception exp) {
            exp.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
    }

  //the event where the second window is opened

  else if(e.getSource() == mod) {
            int id = (int) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0);
            String user = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),2);
            String pass = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),3);
            new Edits().changeUser(user, pass, id);
            this.refreshTable();
        }
```

and this is the code for the second window:

```
//the frame of the second window
public void changeUser(String user,String pass, int id) {
        //init frame
        this.setTitle("Change User Login");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setLocation(dim.width/6-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/16-this.getSize().height/2);
        this.setSize(400, 290);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        //change sizes
        Dimension labels = new Dimension(150,25);
        Dimension inputs = new Dimension(200,25);
        Dimension btn = new Dimension(80,35);
        Dimension btn1 = new Dimension(120,35);
        //labels size
        currentUser.setSize(labels);
        currentUser.setMaximumSize(labels);
        currentUser.setMinimumSize(labels);
        currentUser.setPreferredSize(labels);
        changeUser.setSize(labels);
        changeUser.setMaximumSize(labels);
        changeUser.setMinimumSize(labels);
        changeUser.setPreferredSize(labels);
        currentPass.setSize(labels);
        currentPass.setMaximumSize(labels);
        currentPass.setMinimumSize(labels);
        currentPass.setPreferredSize(labels);
        changePass.setSize(labels);
        changePass.setMaximumSize(labels);
        changePass.setMinimumSize(labels);
        changePass.setPreferredSize(labels);
        //inputs size
        oldUser.setSize(inputs);
        oldUser.setMaximumSize(inputs);
        oldUser.setMinimumSize(inputs);
        oldUser.setPreferredSize(inputs);
        newUser.setSize(inputs);
        newUser.setMaximumSize(inputs);
        newUser.setMinimumSize(inputs);
        newUser.setPreferredSize(inputs);
        oldPass.setSize(inputs);
        oldPass.setMaximumSize(inputs);
        oldPass.setMinimumSize(inputs);
        oldPass.setPreferredSize(inputs);
        newPass.setSize(inputs);
        newPass.setMaximumSize(inputs);
        newPass.setMinimumSize(inputs);
        newPass.setPreferredSize(inputs);
        //button sizes
        okUser.setSize(btn1);
        okUser.setMaximumSize(btn1);
        okUser.setMinimumSize(btn1);
        okUser.setPreferredSize(btn1);
        closeUser.setSize(btn);
        closeUser.setMaximumSize(btn);
        closeUser.setMinimumSize(btn);
        closeUser.setPreferredSize(btn);
        //set layout
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,15));
        //add components
        this.add(currentUser);
        this.add(oldUser);
        this.add(changeUser);
        this.add(newUser);
        this.add(currentPass);
        this.add(oldPass);
        this.add(changePass);
        this.add(newPass);
        this.add(okUser);
        this.add(closeUser);
        //button & input configuration
        oldUser.setEditable(false);
        oldUser.setText(user);
        oldPass.setEditable(false);
        oldPass.setText(pass);
        Id.setValue(id);
        newUser.setText(user);
        newPass.setText(pass);
        okUser.addActionListener(this);
        closeUser.addActionListener(this);
    }

  //the action of the second window

  else if(e.getSource() == okUser) {
            String user = oldUser.getText();
            String pass = oldPass.getText();
            int id = (int) Id.getValue();
            if(!newUser.getText().equals("") && !newPass.getText().equals("")) {
                try {
                    Vector<Object> params = new Vector<Object>();
                    params.add(newUser.getText());
                    params.add(newPass.getText());
                    params.add(id);
                    new dbcon().setUpdates("update users set uname = ?, pwd = ? where id = ?", params);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Informations Updated");
                    this.dispose();
                }catch(Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure to fill out all the fields!");
            }
        }
```

i hope you guys be able to help me out because it's for a school project due in 5 hours. thank you all for your time :D

Comment: Without more context, I would recommend having a look at [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: i didn't get what you meant by more context

Comment: Well, you talk about using two `JFrame`s, if that's true, then the linked I suggest is probably what you're asking, but I only have what you've stated in your question, the code does not replicate the work flow you are using nor the problem you seem to be having, but based on the description I think what you really want is modal dialog

Comment: yeah i've used the JDialog and everything works flawless, thanks alot for your help i really appreciate it, may god bless you :D